# pass parameter to change_form.html in user form of django admin site

Tags: python, parameters, django-admin

I want to pass `songname` list and `songcount` list to user update page at admin side.  I've already extended admin templates.  Just want to know how can I pass custom parameters to user update page.  My codes below

change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_related_objects %}
    <div style="margin:20px">
        <div class="chart_container" style="height: 200px; width:200px; clear: both;">
            <canvas style="width:20px;height:20px;" id="myChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
{%autoescape off%}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: {{songname}}.map(function(e){
            return e.substr(0, 10);
        }),
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Time Played',
            data: {{songcount}},
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

{%endautoescape%}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

To generate list, I need request object.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386533/how-to-pass-context-to-djangoadmins-change-list-results-html

Comment: where should i put this extended template? in myapp/template/ or project/template?