# How to pass context to DjangoAdmin's change_list_results.html

Tags: django, django-admin

I currently have the following in my admin class

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    context = extra_context or {}
    context['econtext'] = 'Extra Context'
    return super(BaseModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=context)
```

However, calling `{{ econtext }}` in my change_list_results.html turns up empty. Am I overriding the wrong method for this?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use changelist_view, but not change_view?

Comment: You doing nothing wrong as of my knowledge. But just re-check you return context in same html template.

Comment: Hi guys! Turns out Suresh was right. I was placing it in the wrong place, causing the output to be absored by an html tag, my bad! Moved it and now my data is showing, thanks!